# How do I calculate a 12-month return based on monthly observations within dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series

How to calculate rolling cumulative product on Pandas DataFrame.

I have a time series of returns in a pandas DataFrame. How can I calculate a rolling annualized alpha for the relevant columns in the DataFrame? I would normally use Excel and do: `=PRODUCT(1+[trailing 12 months])-1`

My DataFrame looks like the below (a small portion):

```
                Unnamed: 1 Unnamed: 2 Unnamed: 3 Unnamed: 4  \
```

2009-08-31 00:00:00        ---        ---     0.1489   0.072377
2009-09-30 00:00:00        ---        ---     0.0662   0.069608
2009-10-31 00:00:00        ---        ---    -0.0288  -0.016967
2009-11-30 00:00:00        ---        ---    -0.0089     0.0009
2009-12-31 00:00:00        ---        ---      0.044   0.044388
2010-01-31 00:00:00        ---        ---    -0.0301  -0.054953
2010-02-28 00:00:00        ---        ---    -0.0014    0.00821
2010-03-31 00:00:00        ---        ---     0.0405   0.049959
2010-04-30 00:00:00        ---        ---     0.0396  -0.007146
2010-05-31 00:00:00        ---        ---    -0.0736  -0.079834
2010-06-30 00:00:00        ---        ---    -0.0658  -0.028655
2010-07-31 00:00:00        ---        ---     0.0535   0.038826
2010-08-31 00:00:00        ---        ---    -0.0031  -0.013885
2010-09-30 00:00:00        ---        ---     0.0503   0.045781
2010-10-31 00:00:00        ---        ---     0.0499   0.025335
2010-11-30 00:00:00        ---        ---      0.012  -0.007495

I've tried the code below provided for a similar question, but it looks like it doesn't work anymore ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# your DataFrame; df = ...

pd.rolling_apply(df, 12, lambda x: np.prod(1 + x) - 1)
```

... and the pages that I'm redirected seem not to be as relevant.

Ideally, I'd like to reproduce the DataFrame but with 12 month returns, not monthly so I can locate the relevant 12 month return depending on the month.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could try something like the below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#define dummy dataframe with monthly returns
df = pd.DataFrame(1 + np.random.rand(20), columns=['returns'])

#compute 12-month rolling returns
df_roll = df.rolling(window=12).apply(np.prod) - 1
```